# Selenium 2.53.1 doesn't seem compatible with Firefox Quantum 64.0.2

Tags: selenium-webdriver

When I try to open any application , it throws below errors.

Firefox version: Firefox Quantum 64.0.2

Code:

```
WebDriver d=new FirefoxDriver();

d.get("https://www.google.com/");
```

Error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
```

Comment: Selenium is way past version **3**. Recent versions of browsers will not work with any Selenium version 2.

Comment: I used selenium version 3 and works fine. Thanks!